# Enterprise Architect and Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to connect a project I have created in Unity3D to Enterprise Architect. What I want is for Unity to be able to see the data about a model in EA's database and then be able to do something with it but I'm having trouble accessing the database.
The automation interface of EA is what I want to be using apparently but I can't really work out what it is or how to use it.
So I guess my question is a) Is what I'm trying to do even possible? and b) if it is, does anyone know of a site or tutorial that could show me how to use the Automation Interface, as I can't seem to find anything and EA's just confuses me

Comment: Put in more effort and eventually you will solve it. Anyhow, with the bread crumbs you gave us, likely nobody will be able to give an answer. Besides that: interesting idea to create a game from EA.

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if it would work with any other language used by Unity3D other than C#, but if its C#, just need to add Interop.EA.dll(found in the Sparx EA install folder) as a reference to your project and add a using statement when you want to use the API.

[here is a link to the official API reference (functions and properties)](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/reference.html)

As to tutorials, [here is a link on basic use of the API from the official documentation](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/automation/setup.html)